# tbats forecast consistently low

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have the code below which has a function PositiveTBATS which trains a tbats model on a time-series, then forecasts it.  The function applies a log transformation to a time-series, after replacing 0 with 0.001 to avoid -inf values for the log transformation.  The log transformation is to keep the forecast from returning negative values.  I then have another piece of code that parallelizes applying the function to multiple time-series.  The problem I'm having is that the higher end of the forecast always seems to be a little lower than the real data.  I was wondering if there are parameters I could adjust in the tbats model that might help get higher forecasted values at the higher end.  The low values of the forecast are pretty close to the real data.

```
##Parallelizing TBATS Model Training

## Making tbats forecast positive
PositiveTBATS<-function(y){
  z<-replace(y,y==0,0.001)
  x <- log(z)
  fit <- tbats(x, use.box.cox=FALSE)
  fit$lambda <- 0
  fit$control$use.box.cox <- TRUE
  fc <- forecast(fit,h=20)
  fc$x <- exp(x)
  fc
}


# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- floor(detectCores()/4)

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(forecast))

tbatsList<-list(mts2DataTs1, mts2DataTs2)

tbatsModels<-parLapply(cl, tbatsList,
                   PositiveTBATS)

stopCluster(cl)


Data:

dput(mts2DataTs1[1:100])
c(50, 48, 47, 41, 33, 24, 23, 24, 25, 31, 36, 48, 56, 68, 79, 
81, 87, 90, 81, 87, 90, 86, 79, 72, 60, 50, 39, 29, 30, 30, 31, 
29, 31, 35, 44, 54, 71, 70, 83, 87, 93, 98, 104, 105, 101, 92, 
94, 83, 76, 66, 64, 55, 48, 42, 38, 33, 34, 36, 47, 51, 58, 65, 
71, 81, 89, 86, 89, 89, 86, 75, 73, 74, 57, 49, 41, 32, 33, 25, 
24, 26, 28, 33, 42, 56, 61, 71, 74, 77, 84, 91, 90, 91, 91, 89, 
93, 90, 79, 66, 66, 48)


dput(mts2DataTs2[1:100])
c(2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 1, 5, 
9, 5, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 5, 6, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 
5, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 7, 3, 
7, 3, 3, 2, 0, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 8, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is seasonal, but you're not specifying seasonal periods in your TBATS function call. You also don't do the inverse transform to the forecast part in your PositiveTBATS function.

Also, I wouldn't use log transformation for either of the series you provided here. Your second series contains a lot of zeros in the training data, and zeros are not exception here. If you don't want negative forecast values, just truncate the forecast at zero.

Modify your tbats function like this and it will do what you want.

```
PositiveTBATS<-function(y){
  fit <- tbats(y, seasonal.periods = 24)
  fc <- forecast(fit,h=20)  
  mean_fc <- pmax(fc$mean,0)
  return(mean_fc)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried it but it didn't improve the forecast.  I didn't mention it before but mts2DataTs1<-msts(na.approx(Datats1),seasonal.periods=c(24,7*24,365*24)), so is it still necessary to include seasonal.periods in the tbats part of the function?

Comment: If you specified the class to be msts with seasonal periods, then you're good. Looks like you're dealing with hourly data. You may want to explore the data with different frequencies, and potentially consider doing some sort of reconciliation of forecasts with different frequencies (e.g. take a look into thief package).